# Having error during Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows, system-installation, ext2

I have Ubuntu on a USB stick. When I boot from it (select boot from this USB), it shows some logs like usual. I also see the Ubuntu logo with 5 dots below, but then I get these:

```
ext2_lookup deleted inode referenced XXXX
```

And I get tons of them, whole screen is flooded with them. What should I do to resolve this?

1. I am using USB 3.0
2. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit
3. I have a 64-bit capable processor
4. I have never installed Linux on this computer

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB stick? It may be that it's improperly installed/configured. If you have a LiveCD to hand, try booting with that and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to consider creating the bootable USB once again from scratch and the most recommended tool for this purpose is Universal USB Installer. And also it would be useful if you provide some info where did the unsuccessful installation go to and are there any linux traces on the computer after the initial attempt?